# Selenium 3.x V is keep skipping the test execution after Firefox 53v launch

Tags: java, selenium

below is the error message I can see

My Config : Firefox 53 and above
Selenium : 3.x
Apache ant: 1.9.7
log4j : 1.2.17
appium : 1.4.13

Issue : I can launch the browser as well as I can login the site but after few activities my test is keep
skipping the further execution steps. The only thing I can highlight is I needed to add Selenium 2.45 too in order to remove some of errors in my java modules.

1497657743317 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:30220
1497657743880 geckodriver::marionette INFO Starting browser \?\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1497657744925 addons.manager ERROR startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"
location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70" data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 <
FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:674 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:837 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3145
< observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1657: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
1497657747357 Marionette INFO Listening on port 51995
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2572: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Jun 16, 2017 5:02:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: Please format your code. Thanks

Comment: It's just an error message , no code. thanks

Comment: @Java123Code So you're saying you have no test cases yet? Just the base install?

Comment: I have the test cases. I have all set up and version jars mentioned above for selenium , appium etc. Issue I am reporting is I can not execute the test case completely. The execution is stopped once my script logged in the site and right after that I can see skip status and test is keep trying to execute remaining steps but can not see correct activity on webpage. So copied the error message I have found in logs. Please advise. thanks

Comment: (Selenium 3.x + Geckodriver 0.16.0 + Firefox 53.0)
  (Selenium 3.x + Geckodriver 0.15.0 + Firefox 53.0)

(Selenium 3.x + Geckodriver 0.17.0 + Firefox 53.0)

all are not working